# Calculating value of two-variable function in VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, function, variables

I have a function `f(x,y) = e^(x+y)` and function in VBA like this:

```
Function Test(n As Integer, x0 As Double, xk As Double, y0 As Double, yk As Double) As Double()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Tablica() As Double
ReDim Tablica(0 To n, 0 To n)
For i = 0 To n
    For j = 0 To n
        Tablica(j, i) = Exp(x0 + i * (xk - x0) / n + y0 + j * (yk - y0) / n)
    Next j
Next i
Test = Tablica

End Function
```

Is there any way to rewrite this code to work with any function like `f(x,y) = x+y` etc.?

Comment: Not quite clear. Are you asking how to use a function as an input to another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your question as how to make the mathematical function an input parameter to the function `test`. There is no very good way to do this in VBA, but what you can do is to define the function in the code module and then use `Application.Run` to invoke the function by name from inside `test`.

Proof of concept:

```
Function test(f As String, n As Integer, x0 As Double, xk As Double, y0 As Double, yk As Double) As Double()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Tablica() As Double
    ReDim Tablica(0 To n, 0 To n)
    
    For i = 0 To n
        For j = 0 To n
            Tablica(j, i) = Application.Run(f, x0 + i * (xk - x0) / n, y0 + j * (yk - y0) / n)
        Next j
    Next i
    test = Tablica
End Function

'used like:

Function g(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
    g = x - y
End Function

Sub test2()
    Range("A1:D4").Value = test("g", 3, 0, 1, 3, 4)
End Sub
```

Note that you don't need to name the called function `f`, so that `test` can work with multiple functions. Unfortunately, VBA lacks a notion of anonymous functions, so you still need to defined your functions as VBA functions (or write your own parser).